# Traverse through .tar.gz directories and concatenate files (without uncompressing the folders)

Tags: python, r, bash, shell, find

I have a folder of about 20000 tar.gz directories, each containing a bunch of files. I want to go in the source folder, traverse through the tar.gz directories (**without decompressing**) and concatenate the files so at the end I will have three big files.

For e.g. I have a root folder `pnoc` which has `.tar.gz` directories, each compressed folder has three folders - `Kallisto`, `RSEM` and `Hugo`. I have uncompressed one such directory and looks like this:

```
pnoc/
├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── C021_0002_001113_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── C021_0003_001409_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── C021_0004_001418_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── C021_0005_001661_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── C021_0007_001669_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── C021_0008_001699_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── C021_0009_001766_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── C021_0010_001774_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── C021_0011_001786_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── C021_0012_001825_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── C021_0013_001872_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── CPBT_0001_1_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── CPBT_0003_1_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── CPBT_0004_1_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── CPBT_0005_1_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── CPBT_0006_1_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── CPBT_0007_1_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── CPBT_0008_1_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── CPBT_0009_1_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
├── IMPROPERLY_PAIRED.C021_0006_001666_tumor_RNASeq.tar.gz
└── pnoc-manifest


C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq
├── Kallisto
│   ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.abundance.h5
│   ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.abundance.tsv
│   └── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.run_info.json
└── RSEM
    ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem.genes.norm_counts.tab
    ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem.genes.raw_counts.tab
    ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem.isoform.norm_counts.tab
    ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem.isoform.raw_counts.tab
    ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem_genes.results
    ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem_isoforms.results
    └── Hugo
        ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem.genes.norm_counts.hugo.tab
        ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem.genes.raw_counts.hugo.tab
        ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem.isoform.norm_counts.hugo.tab
        ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem.isoform.raw_counts.hugo.tab
        ├── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem_genes.hugo.results
        └── C021_0001_20140916_tumor_RNASeq.rsem_isoforms.hugo.results
```

So I want to concatenate all the *.abundance.tsv in one, *.rsem.genes.norm_counts.tab in second and *.rsem_genes.hugo.results in third file. What's the best and most efficient way to do that? I am okay with anything - `R`, `Python` or `Bash`.

```
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION SELINUX FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use python/r? A simple bash script would probably be faster. :)

Comment: Yes, I can use anything, I just want hints to the first part where you go in tar.gz without decompressing and concatenate files.

Answer (score 3):

Using `bash` `find` command as below; The `cat` command in `exec` is applied to all the files returned by the command. The `+` option is to ensure no more than one instance of the `cat` is spawned by the shell.

Here `{}` denotes the files returned the find command. Refer more about [`find -exec`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/moreadv.html)

```
find . -type f -name '*.abundance.tsv' -exec cat "{}" + >> ../AbundanceTSV.tsv
find . -type f -name '*.rsem.genes.norm_counts.tab' -exec cat "{}" + >> ../GenesNormCounts.tab
find . -type f -name '*.rsem_genes.hugo.results' -exec cat "{}" + >> ../HugoResults.results
```

Comment: Can you also explain what the command is doing? Thanks! Why is `../` needed?

Comment: @KomalRathi: Good catch! that is to ensure the output file is not processed by `find` for its input.

Comment: I am getting an empty result. Is it because the second level directories are all compressed? Because I do `find ./pnoc/ -type f -name '*.abundance.tsv'` and it is not returning anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120438/discussion-between-inian-and-komal-rathi).

Comment: I am looking to concatenate files without decompressing the .tar.gz folders.